# In kendo grid, how to know when ajax function starts and ends?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

In my grid I want to call a javascript function when an ajax request is fired by the kendo grid.    When the ajax request ends, I need to fire another javascript function.
Code:

```
@(Html.Kendo()
    .Grid<Aditro.Foundation.Dashboard.Web.Models.Link>()
.Name("LinkGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.Text).Width(100);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Url).Width(250);
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(100);
})
.DataSource(source =>
{
    source.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("GetLinks", "Settings").Data("Grid_OnComplete"))
        .Create(read => read.Action("LinkAddEdit", "Settings"))
        .Events(e => e.RequestStart("callloading"))
        .Update(read => read.Action("LinkAddEdit", "Settings"))
        .Destroy(read => read.Action("LinkDelete", "Settings"))
        .Model(model => { model.Id("LinkId"); model.Field(x => x.Genus_List_Action).Editable(true); model.Field(x => x.Genus_List_Select).Editable(false); });
})
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
.Pageable(pageable =>
{
    pageable.Enabled(true);
    pageable.PageSizes(new[] { 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 });
})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
.Navigatable()
.Selectable(action => action.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
//.Filterable()
.Sortable(sort => sort.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
.Resizable(resizable => resizable.Columns(true))

)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a to upgrade to a newer version which exposes the `RequestEnd` event.

Comment: I tried it 
.Events(e => e.RequestEnd("Stoploading"))
but Stoploading function does not get called :-(